# Remove eventlistener

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

Help:-) How do i remove this listener?

```
this.overlay.addEventListener('click', this._handlePlay.bind(this));
```

_handlePlay looks like this:

```
_handlePlay() {
    this._isOpen = !this._isOpen;
  }
```

i tried...

```
this.overlay.removeEventListener('click', this._handlePlay.bind(this));
```

and more desperately:

```
this.overlay.removeEventListener('click', this._handlePlay());
```

but the listener wont leave the scene?

I have the bind as I am in js and web component context

/regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you pass to `removeEventListener` needs to be the **same** function that you pass to `addEventListener`.

`bind` creates a new function.

> ```
> this.overlay.addEventListener('click', this._handlePlay.bind(this));
> ```

Since you don't keep the value of `this._handlePlay.bind(this)`, there's no way to get that function back to pass it to `removeEventListener`.

---

You need to keep the value somewhere that you can access when you later try to remove the event listener.

```
const boundHandlePlay = this._handlePlay.bind(this);
this.overlay.addEventListener('click', boundHandlePlay);
this.overlay.removeEventListener('click', boundHandlePlay);
```

Comment: aint yo a sweetheart.... thank you SO much